# How to define a macro like defstruct?

Tags: macros, common-lisp

We define a structure like this way

```
(defstruct point
  x 
  y)
```

Then we get a function `point-p`

It seems easy to define a macro

```
(defmacro mac (fun-name)
  `(defun ,fun-name ()
     t))
```

But how can I add "-p" as a suffix on `fun-name` ?
I think it may be something like

```
(defmacro mac (fun-name)
  `(defun ,(suffix ,fun-name) ()
     t))
```

`suffix` may be a function.
So how in fact can I implement this ?

Comment: It's not exactly the same, but I think http://stackoverflow.com/q/24433035/1281433 may have an answer for you, or at least some helpful tips.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You simply use `string` to make a string out of your symbol. Do whatever you'd like with it and `intern` it to get an interned symbol you can use as identifier.

```
(defun suffix (symbol suffix)
  (intern (concatenate 'string (string symbol) (string suffix))))

(defmacro make-predicate (fun-name)
  `(defun ,(suffix fun-name '#:-p) ()
     t))
(make-predicate test)
(test-p) ; ==> t
```

NB: You have an error in your macro as you use the comma (unquote) inside an already unquoted expression.

Comment: Note that passing strings as suffix is going to have problems with readtable's whose case is modified

Comment: string-concat does not seem to be common-lisp. I use: (concatenate 'string ...etc)

Comment: @user115813 `string-concat` is imported into `common-lisp-user` in CLISP, but it's not a part of `CL` package. Changed to `concatenate`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I get it.