# Create a class accessor name from string inside a CL macro

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp, symbols

I am trying the following code to write a macro that, given a name of a class, automatically creates a class with a `name` instance variable and an accessor for it in the form of `classname-name`.

```
(defmacro def-named-class (class-name)
  `(defclass ,class-name ()
    ((name :accessor ,(intern (format nil "~A-~A" class-name "name"))
           :initarg :name
           :initform ""))))
```

The problem here is that, when the macro runs, say with an argument `foo`, the name of the accessor function comes as `|FOO-name|`, but I would want it to be just `foo-name`. The reason is, `(intern "foo-name")` returns a symbol `|foo-name|`. However, if I try to do the same with a normal function, like this:

```
(defmacro def-hyp (name1 name2 arg-list &body body)
  `(defun ,(intern (format nil "~A-~A" name1 name2))
          ,arg-list
          ,@body))
```

And then call it like `(def-hyp foo name () 'foo-name)` it correctly produces a function with name `foo-name`. So I'm wondering if there's any method to get the exact same symbol from the string representation inside the first macro. I am using Clozure CL.

Comment: Do the answers to [combining two variables into one function name in macro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24433035/combining-two-variables-into-one-function-name-in-macro) solve this for you?  Note particularly the part about format in the accepted answer (disclaimer: it's mine).

Answer (score 3):

Note that a class already has a name.

```
CL-USER 19 > (defclass foo () ())
#<STANDARD-CLASS FOO 415040BE6B>

CL-USER 20 > (class-name *)
FOO
```

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it better solved by inheritance? Here is your mixin:

```
(defclass named ()
  ((name :initarg :name :accessor name-of)))
```

... and you can use it for all other classes that define objects which have a name:

```
(defclass this (named) ...)
(defclass that (named) ...)
```

Comment: Yes, of course that is better way to do it. The macro was just an experiment.

Answer (score 1):

You should convert the name to upper case:

```
(defmacro def-named-class (class-name)
  `(defclass ,class-name ()
     ((name :accessor ,(intern (format nil "~A-~A" (string-upcase class-name) "NAME"))
            :initarg :name
            :initform ""))))
```

Another possibility, as suggested in a comment by jkiiski, is to change only the format string:

```
...
((name :accessor ,(intern (format nil "~:@(~A-~A~)" class-name "name"))
...
```

The reason is that the default behaviour of the Common Lisp reader is to transform any symbol in upper-case on reading it. So, when you write `foo-name`, it is automatically transformed into `FOO-NAME`. To obtain it, you should use `(intern "FOO-NAME")`. However, if you want, you can change the default behaviour of the reader (see the [manual](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rdtabl.htm#readtable-case)).

Comment: That worked, thanks. However, I'm wondering why in the case of a normal function in the second case it was able to create the proper name.

Comment: @sourav.d, the reason is that you use symbols to form the new name (the values of `name1` and `name2`), so they are automatically converted in upper case by the reader.

Comment: You could also use `"~:@(~A-~A~)"` to convert to upcase since it's using format anyway.

Comment: Converting to upper case is not sufficient, and can be just as wrong as using lower case names blindly.  What happens if the class or slot name is *supposed* to contain lower case letters?  This has been discussed in [combining two variables into one function name in macro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24433035/combining-two-variables-into-one-function-name-in-macro) (see *Don't (naïvely) create symbol names with format* in my answer there).  A proper solution needs to *preserve* the cases in the symbol names, not change them, and needs to document what will be added as a suffix.